# Given an commutative $C^{*}$ algebra, can we recover the topological dimension of the space(under Gelfrand duality)?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, operator-algebras

Given a commutative $C^{*}$ algebra $A$, by Gelfrand duality, $A$ is homeomorphic to a locally compact Hausdorff space $X$. Then can we know the topological dimension of $X$ from $A$?and how?

My first thought is the Krull dimension, by the maximal length of chain of prime ideal of $A$. But I don't think that is the case.

Comment: You should check Rieffel's work on the Topological Stable Rank.

Comment: Incidentally, commutative C*-algebras don't have any nontrivial chain of prime ideals.

Comment: If a commutative $C^*$-algebra $C_0(X)$ is generated by $n$ self-adjoint elements $x_1,...,x_n$ then $X$ embeds as subset of $\Bbb R^n$:

$$X\cong \{ (\xi(x_1),..., \xi(x_n))\, \mid \xi \text{ a character} \}$$

So the amount of generators you can find provides you an upper bound on the dimensions.